# When i click on next button, the previous question must be remove with reverse animation & next question must be show with typing effect animation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css-animations

i want that When i click on next button, the previous question must be remove with reverse animation effect & next question must be show with typing effect animation, same as next click.., next click... smae steps must be follow.
Anybody can help with this code:
my coide is not working properly.
plz help me:) Thanks in advance.

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <style>
        .rks1 {
font-weight: 900;
font-size: 2.5em;
font-family: rr;
}

.rks1 .letter {
display: inline-block;
line-height: 1em;
}

.word {
white-space: nowrap;
}

.span {
}
    </style>




    <div id="questions">
<div id="q0" class="rks1">
<h3>1. The color of the sky is...? </h3>

</div>
<div id="q1" class="rks1" style="display: none">
<h3>2. Paper comes from...? </h3>

</div>
<div id="q2"  class="rks1" style="display: none">
<h3>3. How many hours in a day? </h3>

</div>
</div>
    <br> <br>
<button onclick="next()">Next Question</button>




    <script type="text/javascript">    
var textWrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.rks1');

textWrappers.forEach(textWrapper => {
  textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/(\S*)/g, m => {
    return `<span class="word">` +
      m.replace(/(-|)?\S(-|@)?/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>") +
      `</span>`;
  });
});

var targets = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.rks1 .letter'));

anime.timeline({
    loop: true,
  })
  .add({
    targets: targets,
    scale: [3, 1],
    scaleY: [1.5, 1],
    opacity: [0, 1],
    translateZ: 0,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 400,
    delay: (el, i) => 60 * i
  }).add({
    targets: targets.reverse(),
    scale: [1,3],
    scaleY: [1,1.5],
    opacity: [1,0],
    translateZ: 0,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 100,
    delay: (el, i) => 30*i
  }).add({
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 100
  })
    </script>
    


   <script>
var showing = [1, 0, 0];
var questions = ['q0', 'q1', 'q2'];
function next() {
    var qElems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
        qElems.push(document.getElementById(questions[i]));   
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < showing.length; i++) {
        if (showing[i] == 1) {
            qElems[i].style.display = 'none';
            showing[i] = 0;
            if (i == showing.length - 1) {
                qElems[0].style.display = 'block';
                showing[0] = 1;
            } else {
                qElems[i + 1].style.display = 'block';
                showing[i + 1] = 1;
            }
            break;
        }
    }      
}

   </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your animation code only really requires the following as you can make use of animejs's **reverse** timeline feature:

```
var anim = anime.timeline()
  .add({
    targets: targets,
    scale: [3, 1],
    scaleY: [1.5, 1],
    opacity: [0, 1],
    translateZ: 0,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 400,
    delay: (el, i) => 60 * i
  })
```

Below is an example of the reverse animation once the **next** function is run.
A promise is also used for once the animation has completed.

```
function next() {
  anim.reverse();
  anim.complete = () => {
    // next question...
  };     
}
```

You can continue your logic within this callback to load your next questions.

---

Final result, slight tidy up

```js
var question = 0,
  questions = [
        "The color of the sky is...?",
      "Paper comes from...?",  
      "How many hours in a day?"];
    
var anim,
    targets;

function prepQuestion() {
  $("#questions").text(questions[question]);
      
  var textWrappers = document.querySelectorAll('#questions');
  textWrappers.forEach(textWrapper => {
    textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/(\S*)/g, m => {
      return `<span class="word">` +
        m.replace(/(-|)?\S(-|@)?/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>") +
        `</span>`;
    });
  });
  
  targets = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#questions .letter'));

  anim = anime.timeline()
    .add({
      targets: targets,
      scale: [3, 1],
      scaleY: [1.5, 1],
      opacity: [0, 1],
      translateZ: 0,
      easing: "easeOutExpo",
      duration: 400,
      delay: (el, i) => 60 * i
    });
}

// init
prepQuestion();

function next() {
  anim = anime.timeline()
    .add({
      targets: targets.reverse(),
      scale: [1,3],
      scaleY: [1,1.5],
      opacity: [1,0],
      translateZ: 0,
      easing: "easeOutExpo",
      duration: 100,
      delay: (el, i) => 30 * i
    });
        
  anim.complete = () => {
    if (question == questions.length - 1) { question = 0; } // reset question
    else { question++; }
    
    prepQuestion();
  };     
}
```

```css
#questions {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-family: rr;
}

#questions .letter {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.word {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="questions"></div>
<button onclick="next()">Next Question</button>
```

Of course this is just a rough idea and a slightly different approach.

Comment: answer updated. questions loop, animation duration decreased.